# Regular expression literal-text span

Tags: regex, tcl

Is there any way to indicate to a regular expression a block of text that is to be searched for explicitly?  I ask because I have to match a very very long piece of text which contains all sorts of metacharacters (and (and has to match exactly), followed by some flexible stuff (enough to merit the use of a regex), followed by more text that has to be matched exactly.

Rinse, repeat.

Needless to say, I don't really want to have to run through the entire thing and have to escape every metacharacter.  That just makes it a bear to read.  Is there a way to wrap those portions so that I don't have to do this?

**Edit:**

Specifically, I am using Tcl, and by "metacharacters", I mean that there's all sorts of long strings like "`**$^{*$%\)`".  I would really not like to escape these.  I mean, it would add thousands of characters to the string.  Does Tcl regexp have a literal-text span metacharacter?

Comment: Can you give an example? It's not clear exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Depending on your language, you can use a function like `Regex.escape()` that will escape a string for you automatically.

Comment: What regular-expression-library/programming-language are you doing this for?  Normally regular expressions use regular text for 'exact matches' only requiring that you escape re specific stuff, except that whether you escape the re-specific stuff or the regular text depends on the library.

Comment: The test that is seached doesn't have (regex) metacharacters. It's just literal text

Comment: If you are able to build a regex from a string then just escape it first and then compile the regex..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way of doing this in Tcl is to use a helper procedure to do the escaping, like this:

```
proc re_escape str {
    # Every non-word char gets a backslash put in front
    regsub -all {\W} $str {\\&}
}

set awkwardString "**$^{*$%\\)"
regexp "simpleWord *[re_escape $awkwardString] *simpleWord" $largeString
```

Where you have a whole literal string, you have two other alternatives:

```
regexp "***=$literal" $someString
regexp "(?q)$literal" $someString
```

However, both of these only permit patterns that are pure literals; you can't mix patterns and literals that way.

Answer (score 0):

No, tcl does not have such a feature.

If you're concerned about readability you can use variables and commands to build up your expression. For example, you could do something like:

```
set fixed1 {.*?[]}  ;# match the literal five-byte sequence .*?[]
set fixed2 {???}    ;# match the literal three byte sequence ???
set pattern "this.*and.*that"

regexp "[re_escape $fixed1]$pattern[re_escape $fixed2]"
```

You would need to supply the definition for `re_escape` but the solution should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 0):

A Tcl regular expression can be specified with the `q` metasyntactical directive to indicate that the expression is literal text:

```
% set string {this string contains *emphasis* and 2+2 math?}
% puts [regexp -inline -all -indices {*} $string]
couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid
% puts [regexp -inline -all -indices {(?q)*} $string]
{21 21} {30 30}
```

This does however apply to the entire expression.

What I would do is to iterate over the returned indices, using them as arguments to `[string range]` to extract the other stuff you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Perl and Java support the \Q  \E escape. so

`\Q.*.*()\E`

..will actually match the literal "`.*.*()`"

**OR**

Bit of a hack but replace the literal section with some text which does not need esacping *and that will not appear elsewhere in your searched string*. Then build the regex using this meta-character-free text. A 100 digit random sequence for example. Then when your regex matches at a certain postion and length in the doctored string you can calculate whereabouts it should appear in the original string and what length it should be.

Comment: @Bryan Thanks for the -1 but I posted this before the OP had stated which platform he was using :)

Comment: @El Ronnoco: understood. You might want to delete your answer since its not applicable.

Comment: @Bryan: I think it's still applicable as someone searching for a way to do this may be using another platform. The platform is not specified in the OP's question summary.

Comment: @El: You can see the explanation; it's the upvoted comment. In short, your answer does not solve the question *as it currently stands*.